# Maven - Include dependent libs in jar without unpacking dependencies?

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin, client-library

We're trying to build a client jar that includes *unpacked* dependent jar's.  And the manifest should have `class-path` entries to the dependent jars.  The snippet below works but the jars are unpacked - how can we stop the jars from being unpacked?

```
       <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>

                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Indeed, assembling using `jar-with-dependencies` causes maven to unpack all the dependencies as `${assembly.dependencySets.dependency.unpack}` is set to `true` in the corresponding assembly descriptor.

A simple fix would be to provide an assembly descriptor similar to the `jar-with-dependencies.xml` and modify `${assembly.dependencySets.dependency.unpack}` to `false`, like this:

**EDIT:** For an unknown reason, the behavior when using `<unpack>false</unpack>` is not exactly the same and it seems necessary to add `<outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>` to the fileSet or you don't get the expected result.

```
<assembly>
  <id>uberjar</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <unpack>false</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: I would also add `<dependencySets><dependencySet><useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact></dependencySet></dependencySets>`.

Answer (score 8):

You can add your dependencies as jar files to your jar:

**assembly-descriptor.xml**

```
<assembly>
    <id>uberjar</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-uberjar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>src/main/assemble/assembly-descriptor.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But unfortunately you can't use the `Class-Path` header in `manifest.mf`, see [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html):

> **Note:** The `Class-Path` header points to classes or JAR files on the local network, not JAR files within the JAR file or classes accessible over Internet protocols. To load classes in JAR files within a JAR file into the class path, you must write custom code to load those classes. For example, if `MyJar.jar` contains another JAR file called `MyUtils.jar`, you cannot use the `Class-Path` header in `MyJar.jar's` manifest to load classes in `MyUtils.jar` into the class path.

Answer (score 3):

The solution proposed by Pascal Thivent defines a new assembly for the Maven assembly plugin. The Maven assembly plugin offers defaults assemblies which are 'bin', 'jar-with-dependencies', 'project' and 'src' producing various predefined bundles.

A new assembly has to be defined in a new xml file, most of the time located in src/assemble. Then it will be loaded instead of the predefined one, this way:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
      <configuration>

          <!-- disabled predefined assembly -->
          <!--
          <descriptorRefs>
             <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          -->

          <descriptors>
             <descriptor>src/assemble/myAssembly.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```